# How can I differentiate the expected value of a utility function?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, expected-value, utility

Suppose I have a maximisation problem
$$\underset{0\le R(y)\le y} \max E\left\{u_B\left[ y-R( y)\right]\right\}$$
subject to$$E\left\{u_L\left[R( y)\right]\right\}\ge \bar U_L$$
$B$ and $L$ are simply two people, with respective utility function
$\bar U_L $ is just a constant.

$y$ is the possible return on a project, which should have a probability density function $f(y)$, while $R(y)$ is the amount of the return that goes to agent $L$.

To solve the question, I construct the Lagrangian equation
$$\mathcal{L}=E\left\{u_B\left[ y-R( y)\right]\right\}+\lambda\left[E\left\{u_L\left[R( y)\right]\right\}-\bar U_L\right]$$
I, however, don't know how to calculate $$\partial \mathcal{L}\over \partial R(y)$$
I am not familiar with differentiating the expected value of a continuous function.

Comment: If you didn't have to differentiate, what would your next step be? That is, how would you calculate the expected values?

Comment: The expected value is irrelevant. I need to use the result of this differentiation to find the optimal R(y). The result is in fact $${\partial \mathcal{L}\over \partial R(y)}=-u'_B\left[y-R(y)\right]f(y)+\lambda u'_L\left[R(y)\right]f(y)=0$$, but I don't understand the mechanism.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, for a random variable $X$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$, the expected value is $E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) dP(\omega)$. You have the probability density of $y$, substitute in the appropriate integral and differentiate.